# How do i get letters to randomly generate in my output?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to randomly generate the letter "D" & "C" in my 2d array 
so output would look like this

0 0 0 0 0

0 D 0 C 0

C 0 D 0 D

D C 0 0 0

0 D 0 C D
then generate again but everything randomly in a different place

C D 0 C D

C 0 0 D C

0 0 0 C 0

0 D 0 C D

D 0 C 0 C

... and so on

public class Array {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create 2-dimensional array.
    int[][] values = new int[5][5];

    String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        // Loop and display sub-arrays.
        int[] sub = values[i];
        for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");

        }

        for (int x = 0; x < values[0].length; x++) {

            for (int y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
                int x = (int) (Math.random() * 26); // random int between 0-25
                String letter = "" + s.charAt(x); //concatenates
                values[x][y] = letter; // declares.
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I see that you have implemented my first solution.. This question is also an easy fix as you just edit the values in the string. and change the highest index the random number can go.

Comment: I keep getting a error im not sure where to put the code thats below

Comment: Whats the error can you put that in the post

Comment: int x = (int)(Math.random()*3); 
   String letter = ""+s.charAt(x); 
   values[x][y] = letter;

THat is where the error is

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would need....

```
String s = "0CD"; ////HEREs WHATS DIFFERENT
//loop through rows
for(int x = 0; x< values[0].length;x++)
{
//loops through columns
 for(int y = 0; y< values.length;y++)
 { 
   int x = (int)(Math.random()*3); // HEREs WHATS DIFFERENT
   String letter = ""+s.charAt(x); //concatenates
   values[x][y] = letter; // declares.
  }
}
```

I marked the values that you need to change and what they should be changed too